# c++ : convert vector to tuple

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples

How can I convert std::vector to std::tuple ?
I have

```
class T { };
int cnt = 3;
vector<T*> tv;
for (int i = 0; i < cnt; ++i) {
  tv.push_back(new T());
}
```

I want to get

```
auto tp = std::tie(*tv[0], *tv[1], *tv[2]);
```

How can I get this tp ?
If cnt is big enough, I can't write this tp manually.

```
  std::vector<
  ConvConnection<
  decltype(inputLayer),
  decltype(*C1[0]),
  decltype(*Conn1Opt[0]),
  RandomInitialization<arma::mat>,
  arma::mat
  >* > Conn1(6);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
    Conn1.push_back(new  ConvConnection<
                    decltype(inputLayer),
                    decltype(*C1[0]),
                    decltype(*Conn1Opt[0]),
                    RandomInitialization<arma::mat>,
                    arma::mat
                    >(inputLayer, *C1[i], *Conn1Opt[i], 5, 5));
  }
```

This is the code. Here is just 6, but I also need some vector whose size is over 100. I need to convert this vector to a tuple.

Comment: If it's too large or cumbersome to write manually, write another program that generates it. If you want to determine the tuple's size at runtime, you can't.

Comment: Why do you need a tuple? Wouldn't `std::array<T*,MAX>` work?

Comment: An off-topic nitpick: You should really have better variable/class names. There's no reason `cnt` can't be written as `count`. What is a `ConvConnection`? `Conn1Opt`? In 2015, your source files will still fit on your hard drive with a few extra characters in them, and other developers who look at your code will thank you later :)

Answer (score 19):

Generally, you cannot convert a `vector` to a `tuple`. However, if all you're trying to do is make the tuple `<f(0), f(1), ..., f(N-1)>` for some `N` that is a constant-expression, then that is doable with the index sequence trick:

```
template <typename F, size_t... Is>
auto gen_tuple_impl(F func, std::index_sequence<Is...> ) {
    return std::make_tuple(func(Is)...);
}

template <size_t N, typename F>
auto gen_tuple(F func) {
    return gen_tuple_impl(func, std::make_index_sequence<N>{} );
}
```

Which we can use like:

```
// make a tuple of the first 10 squares: 0, 1, 4, ..., 81
auto squares = gen_tuple<10>([](size_t i){ return i*i;});
```

For your specific use-case, that would be:

```
auto connections = gen_tuple<6>([&](size_t i) {
    return new ConvConnection<
                decltype(inputLayer),
                decltype(*C1[0]),
                decltype(*Conn1Opt[0]),
                RandomInitialization<arma::mat>,
                arma::mat
                >(inputLayer, *C1[i], *Conn1Opt[i], 5, 5);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But I need tuple <T1, T2, .... ,TN> where each Ti is a class. I use this to build a neuron network. Because current framework of the NN uses tuple, but now my network is too big that I can write it manually. It seems I have to change the framework or generate it use another program.

Comment: @HurricaneTong You can do this with classes too. Just replace `make_tuple(Is...)` with `make_tuple(new T(Is)...)`.

Comment: I update the question and give my real code. Each class in the tuple has different parameter for construction. Can you help me with this?

Comment: @JaraxussTong Updated my answer to allow for a function that you can pass in.

Answer (score 16):

If you have C++14, you can do it like this:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t... Indices>
auto vectorToTupleHelper(const std::vector<T>& v, std::index_sequence<Indices...>) {
  return std::make_tuple(v[Indices]...);
}

template <std::size_t N, typename T>
auto vectorToTuple(const std::vector<T>& v) {
  assert(v.size() >= N);
  return vectorToTupleHelper(v, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}
```

Thanks to auto deduction, this is ok. In C++11, without auto deduction, you have to write the return types with trailing `decltype`. You also have to implement your own `index_sequence`.

Comment: I know this is a rather old question, but how one would write template arguments without auto deduction but with c++17 support?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know - I've not kept up with C++ post-14.

Answer (score 6):

You just can't. Because the vector size is known at runtime, but `tuple` type (which includes its size) must be known at compile time.

Comment: Then how can I get a 'large' tuple ? I want to get 
auto tp = std::tie(T1, T2, T3, ..... TN)
Suppose N is large enough, I have to generate T1 ... TN dynamic.
Suppose N is fixed when I write code.

Comment: what is 'large' tuple?