# Conversion of vector or array to a list of arguments in C++

Tags: c++, arguments, c++14

I have a third-party library that implements overloaded functions with homogeneous input parameters, like:

```
int foo(int a);
int foo(int a, int b);
int foo(int a, int b, int c);
...
```

Now I would like to write a wrapper that would accept the parameters packed in  vector (or alternatively an array):

```
int foo_wrapper(vector<int>& foo_args);
```

How can I do this?

I have looked at [this answer on converting vector to tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28411055)  for a hint, but it gives me an error:

```
$ g++ -std=c++14 -o test.a test.cpp
test.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
test.cpp:23:20: error: no matching function for call to 'vectorToTuple(std::vector<int>&)'
     vectorToTuple(v);
                    ^
test.cpp:16:6: note: candidate: template<long unsigned int N, class T> auto vectorToTuple(const std::vector<T>&)
 auto vectorToTuple(const std::vector<T>& v) {
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:16:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:23:20: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'N'
     vectorToTuple(v);
                    ^
```

with `test.cpp` being

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

int foo(int a) {return a;};
int foo(int a, int b) {return a+b;};
int foo(int a, int b, int c) {return a+b+c;};

template <typename T, std::size_t... Indices>
auto vectorToTupleHelper(const std::vector<T>& v, std::index_sequence<Indices...>) {
  return std::make_tuple(v[Indices]...);
}

template <std::size_t N, typename T>
auto vectorToTuple(const std::vector<T>& v) {
  //assert(v.size() >= N);
  return vectorToTupleHelper(v, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::vector<int> v={1,2};
    vectorToTuple(v);
}
```

Comment: To eliminate that error the answer is obvious, supply an `N`: `vectorToTuple<2>(v);` don't know if that actually solves your problem, where are you invoking `foo`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question is very difficult to answer generically with `std::vector` but relatively simple with `std::array` or `std::tuple`. Since you specified in your question that `std::array` would be fine, your example can be made to work fine with just a few tweaks.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

int foo(int a) {return a;};
int foo(int a, int b) {return a+b;};
int foo(int a, int b, int c) {return a+b+c;};

template <std::size_t N, typename T, std::size_t... Indices>
auto call_foo_helper(const std::array<T, N>& v, std::index_sequence<Indices...>) {
  return foo(std::get<Indices>(v)...);
}

template <std::size_t N, typename T>
auto call_foo(const std::array<T, N>& v) {
  return call_foo_helper<N>(v, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::array<int, 2> v={1,2};
    auto x = call_foo(v); // x = 1 + 2 = 3
    return 0;
}
```

Edit:

This also works for `std::tuple` by changing `std::array` to `std::tuple` and changing the template statements to match.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

int foo(int a) {return a;};
double foo(int a, double b) {return a+b;};
double foo(int a, double b, int c) {return a+b+c;};

template <typename... T, std::size_t... Indices>
auto call_foo_helper(const std::tuple<T...>& v, std::index_sequence<Indices...>) {
  return foo(std::get<Indices>(v)...);
}

template <typename... T>
auto call_foo(const std::tuple<T...>& v) {
  return call_foo_helper(v, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(T)>());
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    auto v = std::make_tuple(1, 2.0);
    auto x = call_foo(v);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but it only works if all the parameters of the overloaded functions share the same type.

Comment: The same type is OK

Comment: @FelixLauer not sure thats relevant since in the question itself all the parameters are of the same type as well.

Comment: @Eddge I know. I just wanted to state that this is not an entirely generic approach ;)

Answer (score 2):

Function overload resolution is done at compile-time, and since the size of `std::vector<>` is only known at run-time, you have to execute code:

```
int foo_wrapper(std::vector<int>& foo_args)
{
    switch (foo_args.size())
    {
        case 1: return foo(foo_args[0]);
        case 2: return foo(foo_args[0], foo_args[1]);
        case 3: return foo(foo_args[0], foo_args[1], foo_args[2]);
        default:
            throw std::range_error("Incorrect number of arguments.");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::vector<int> v = { 1,2 };
    std::cout << foo_wrapper(v);
}
```

As mentioned in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41467941/8877), the size of `std::array<>` is known at compile time, which allows for a different solution.

Comment: In C++17 you can replace the switch with a fold expression. Sadly the question is tagged `c++14`.