# Calling a function with a vector of arguments

Tags: c++, c++14, dry, variadic

I have a `std::vector` of arguments and I would like to call a function with them. Is there any way to do this?

In particular the function is the `mysqlx` [select](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-cpp/8.0/classmysqlx_1_1_table.html#a24da70a98a65ba2110e35e5fd8b0fc89) function and the arguments are the columns I'm trying to query; they will all be of type `std::string`. The purpose of the function is to reduce duplication in the codebase.

(This seems like a generally useful topic, but I could not find an answer through search. If I missed it and this has already been answered, please point me to the question and close this as a duplicate, thanks.)

Comment: Do you know the size of the vector at compile time?

Comment: "I have a std::vector of arguments and I would like to call a function with them. Is there any way to do this?" Yes. By calling the function, passing the vector as its argument and creating the SQL statement by looping over the vector.

Comment: Can you add some code to show what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @Artyer No, the vector will have different sizes.

Comment: whats wrong with `foo(vec[0],vec[1],vec[2]);` ? Please elaborate, if possible with some example of what code you would like to write

Comment: or do you mean `foo(vec[0]); foo(vec[1]);...` ? The question really isnt 100% clear

Comment: @user463035818 The vector will have variable length, and I need to pass exactly the number of arguments given.

Comment: @user463035818 So `foo()` if the vector is of length 0, `foo(vec[0])` if it is of length 1, `foo(vec[0], vec[1])` if it is of length 2, and so on.

Comment: Whats the problem with vector<vector<>> ? Something like this `typedef std::vector<std::string> args;
 std::vector<args> arg_repo;`

Comment: unfortunately turning a vector to a tuple seems only possible for fixed sized vectors (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28410697/c-convert-vector-to-tuple)) otherwise you could use `std::apply`. Is `foo` "truly variadic" (ie any number of arguments) or only up to some N (eg 0 up to 5 arguments)?

Comment: @Charles For what reason you cannot call the function just as `foo(vec)`? If the vector length is not fixed during compile time, there is no way you can use variadic parameters **by design**.

Comment: @Jodocus It's not my function, it's a library function (from mysqlx, as linked above).

Comment: Are the parts of your code that populate these vectors using fixed amounts, or is it run-time all the way up?

Comment: @Caleth I'm only just starting to DRY the code out and find all the places where this paradigm is used. It's entirely possible that it would not be called with more than a dozen arguments. Certainly 8-10 arguments is fairly common.

Comment: I mean are you only doing `std::vector<ArgT> args = { A, B, C };`, vs ever doing `std::vector<ArgT> args = fromUi()`? In the first case you have the compile time number 3, you just need to retain it. In the second case you don't

Comment: why not index through the vector with a range based for loop and call the function in the body of the loop with the index value as the argument?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it, up to a compile time maximum number of arguments. It isn't pretty.

```
using result_type = // whatever
using arg_type = // whatever
using args_type = const std::vector<arg_type> &;
using function_type = std::function<result_type(args_type)>;

template <size_t... Is>
result_type apply_vector_static(args_type args, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return select(args[Is]...);
}

template<size_t N>
result_type call_apply_vector(args_type args)
{ 
    return apply_vector_static(args, std::make_index_sequence<N>()); 
}

template <size_t... Is>
std::map<size_t, function_type> make_funcs(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return { { Is, call_apply_vector<Is> }... };
}

result_type apply_vector(args_type args)
{
    // Some maximum limit
    static const auto limit = std::make_index_sequence<50>();
    static const auto funcs = make_funcs(limit);
    return funcs.at(args.size())(args);
}
```

[See it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34e53c608a14d87f)

Comment: What is this syntax `= [](args_type args)`? My compiler seems to be confused. (I have `args_type` as `const std::vector<std::string> &`.)

Comment: Oops, variable templates are C++17. It was a variable template initialised from a lambda. Turns out a plain function template is sufficient there

Comment: Now it's choking on `return { { Is, call_apply_vector<Is>... } }` with `error: parameter packs not expanded with ‘...’`. I tweaked it a few ways but haven't managed to get it to compile.